# Ability to return exception/error detail in FatalError Dlg

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.6

I created my own dialog and had a property known as ACTIVATIONERROR which is set via a custom action. When it gets to the fatal error dialog it never displays as expected.

Example:

```
<Control Id="Description4" Type="Text" X="135" Y="110" Width="220" Height="80" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Error}The error was:" />
            <Control Id="Description2" Indirect="yes" Type="Text" X="200" Y="110" Width="220" Height="80" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="ACTIVATIONERROR" Property="ACTIVATIONERROR" />
```

Is there something specifically on the property I have to set such as Secure property/has to be defined etc, I need to set because it acts as if it's blank.

The verbose log illustrates it's getting set:

`MSI (s) (54!D8) [16:52:13:727]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTIVATIONERROR property. Its value` `is 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.'.`

Anybody have any idea what's going on?

C0heers,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your control text should be:

```
[ACTIVATIONERROR]
```

Windows Installer uses the [formatted type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for installer properties.

Also, static text controls support indirection only for their [text styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since ACTIVATIONERROR is the actual text, you should remove *Indirect* and *Property* attributes for your element.